# 2D matrix python increment

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to create a function in python that increments each value in 2D matrix by 10 percent.

```
import numpy
def add_percent(mtrx):
    for i in mtrx:
        for j in i:
            mtrx[i][j] += 1.1


test_mat = np.array([[86, 70, 80, 89],[92, 85, 87, 87],[73, 77, 94, 83]])

test_case = add_percent(test_mat)
```

It throw me a error

Comment: Reading [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Comment: What about `x *= 1.1`? This question is not about programming, it's about basic maths.